# Strchr not working or I need an alternative that checks if any of the characters in a given string are part of another one

Tags: c++, string, codeblocks, fstream, strchr

So I'm trying to check a string and see if it:

1. has 8 or more chars
2. has at least one uppercase letter
3. has at least one lowercase letter
4. has at least one of the following chars .,?!;:_!@#

Here's my code:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
char a[51];
int n,i,countcheck,hardc;
int main()
{
    ifstream fin("parole.in");
    ofstream fout("parole.out");
    fin >> n;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        fin >> a;
        if(strlen(a)>=8)countcheck++;
        if(strchr(a,'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'))countcheck++;
        if(strchr(a,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))countcheck++;
        if(strchr(a,'.,?!;:_!@#'))countcheck++;
        if (countcheck==4)hardc++;
        countcheck=0;
    }
    fout << hardc << '\n';
    fin.close();
    fout.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'` isn't a valid string literal. This should be `"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"`.

Comment: Oh,but it still doesn't work. Now it says invalid conversion from const char* to int.

Comment: `strchr` takes a character as it's second argument. It returns the pointer to the first instance of this character found. If you want to find any of the desired characters you'd better iterate through the string manually and check its existence in your set of characters (possibly using the very same `strchr`).

Comment: Also since it's c++, you'd better use `std::string` and algorithms like `std::find_if` or `std::count_if`.

Answer (score 2):

In C++, favour using `std::string` to character arrays. You can then use algorithms like `std::any_of` and/or `std::string::find_first_of`. Here is an example using both:

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

bool checkString(const std::string& str)
{
    return str.length() >= 8
        && std::any_of(str.begin(), str.end(), ::isupper)
        && std::any_of(str.begin(), str.end(), ::islower)
        && str.find_first_of(".,?!;:_@#") != std::string::npos;
}
```

Usage of `checkString`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string tests[] {
        "Test.123",
        "Test#@#$",
        ".,?!;:_@",
        "7Chars!",
        "abcd.123",
        "ABCD.123"
    };

    for (const auto& s : tests)
        std::cout << s << (checkString(s) ? " \t-GOOD\n" : " \t-BAD\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Test.123    -GOOD
Test#@#$    -GOOD
.,?!;:_@    -BAD
7Chars!     -BAD
abcd.123    -BAD
ABCD.123    -BAD
```

[Live Demo](http://rextester.com/FYW14864)